# ¿Como puedo extraer los datos de esta URL JSON mediante javascript y html?

Tags: javascript, json

Quiero extraer los datos de un [json](/questions/tagged/json) mediante [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) y [html](/questions/tagged/html). Lo que necesito es mostrar los valores de las propiedades `id` y `name`.

- [Esta](https://las.api.pvp.net/api/lol/las/v1.4/summoner/by-name/mohademago?api_key=RGAPI-ab75f917-5785-45e5-aa33-df9755cd4b66) es la URL de la API.
- La respuesta es la siguiente:

  ```
      {
        "mohademago": {
          "id": 4294825,
          "name": "mohademago",
          "profileIconId": 1594,
          "revisionDate": 1491930966000,
          "summonerLevel": 30
        }
      }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

La forma mas sencilla es usar

> jQuery

```
objetoJS = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON);
```

después lo puedes usar como cualquier objeto JS:

```
objetoJS["attributo"]
```

en tu caso funcionaria algo asi

```
function parseJSON(){

            $.get( "https://las.api.pvp.net/api/lol/las/v1.4/summoner/by-
                    name/mohademago",
                    {api_key:"RGAPI-ab75f917-5785-45e5-aa33-df9755cd4b66"}
                 ).done(function( JSON ) {  


                var objectJS = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON);
                var ID=objectJS['mohademago']['id'];
                var NAME=objectJS['mohademago']['name'];

            }); 
        }
```

Comment: No veo la etiqueta [tag:jQuery] en su publicación ;)